# Condensing CSS Styles into One Style

Tags: css

Consider the following CSS styles...

```
.Center { text-align: center; }
.R { float: right; }
#TopImage { background: #0ff; }
```

If I want to apply all three styles to an element, I would just do this...

```
<div class="R Center" id="TopImage">
```

But if I'm going to use this combination of styles hundreds of times, it would be easier to replace them with a single style...

```
.All_Together ( background: #0ff; text-align: center; float: right; )
<div class="All_Together">
```

I'd like to know if, rather than define All_Together separately, I could simply define it like this:

```
.All_Together = .Center + .R + #TopImage
```

Obviously, it couldn't be written exactly like that. But is there a way to tell my webpages that every instance .All_Together has all the values of .Center, .R and #TopImage. Or, to put it another way, how can I make .All_Together inherit the values of several other specific classes and/or id's?

Comment: You can’t. You can however use some preprocessor with mixins; you would mix some rules into another selector. FWIW, `R` and `Center` are *terrible* class names.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) are (in part) made for this very purpose.

They allow you to define classes in such a way that, you can then combine them together, and when you compile the LESS or SASS into CSS you will have the three individual class styles, but also your combined.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to check something before i give the final answer, why can't you just use:

```
.All_Together{
text-align:center;
float:right;
background:#0ff;
}
```

and link it to an external stylesheet so if you make a change to the css it reflects on all pages that use that style?

Alternatively i'd advise to looking in LESS, its a brilliant tool which lets you do exactly what you stated. You can set variables that can be compiled into separate styles. More information at: [LESS Website](http://lesscss.org)

Answer (score 0):

Well, It would be easier instead of renaming EVERYTHING into one style, so why not have a bunch? Simply:

```
 #TopImage, .R, .Center { 
    text-align:center; 
    float:right; 
    background:#0ff; 
}
```

Notice the commas. Should work just fine. Also I'm not sure if you noticed but make it a habit not to put spaces between properties like this: `color: #FFFFFF`. Sometimes CSS acts weird with that. Just a side thing. Hope this Helps!

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware that those kinds of spaces could make CSS act weird; maybe that's the cause of some of the bugs I get from time to time.